# Is it safe to connect DC equipment to a charging battery?

Tags: batteries, ac, dc, solar-energy

I have an off-grid house with a central 24 V setup of batteries and solar panels.

During the day, the voltage of those batteries changes quite a lot, based on power consumption and the solar panels' energy generation. On a typical day the voltage goes from 26.3 V in the morning to 29.2 V maximum and then fluctuates until the sun goes down at 26.7 V and slowly drops until the next morning.

Typical AC powered electronics are just DC devices with an AC power supply that convert to a continous fixed DC voltage, ehich is fine for most consumers.

In my case, I have a core DC infrastructure that I would rather use directly as energy source instead of wasting a lot of power from DC batteries -> AC Inverter -> DC power-supply.

I'm already using this strategy to power some electronic devices (single-board computer, network switch, etc.) using various DC-DC converters that provide a specific output such as 5 V.

What about 24 VDC electronic equipment, such as Wifi PoE access-points and my 3D printer?

Is it safe to directly plug them to my 24 VDC core, or will a sunny blue sky that cranks it up to 29.2 V destroy them?

Comment: If experienced in creating your own circuits and boards, search for DC 24V buck-boost, boost-buck, SEPIC or similar regulator which can take in a wider range of voltages than your batteries could ever supply and output the desired (regulated) DC voltage.  Such regulators are often quite efficient, so will overall work better than DC-AC-DC.  Might be able to find some with adjustable output voltage, and add a potentiometer and/or selector switch.

Answer (score 6):

Probably not safe.  It depends on the device, but probably not safe.  Is it possible that the OEM skimped on the wall wart and ran the power input straight into a 9-36V input DC-DC converter?  Yes.  Is it possible that they decided to cut corners and put 25V caps right on the input?  Also yes.  Without cracking your devices open and checking every component up to the first voltage conversion, it's impossible to say.  Double check the manuals, sometimes they will specify a range of input voltages.

Answer (score 3):

Most DC powered devices usually expect a certain voltage and a 24 V system (that can be anything between 20 V and 30 V) doesn't have accurate enough voltage.

There are DC-to-DC adapters widely available:

- You may find car cigarette lighter plug DC adapters with multiple output voltages, usually around ~2 A current capability, and many of them are designed to work on both 12 V systems and 24 V systems. You can use such an adapter.
- It's also reasonably easy to find systems that provide around ~12 V from a 24 V battery. These are intended for devices that work on a 12 V car system but not on a 24 V big truck system. Usually these are larger in current capacity: they may handle even 10 A. However, usually they aren't exactly 12 volts but rather some stable voltage that's a good average for the 12 V lead-acid system voltage. Let's say 13.5 volts. These 24 V to 12 V converters usually have fixed wires for installation.
- You can find USB adapters and outlets (both for cigarette lighter socket and also with fixed wires) for cars and trucks. Many will work with both 12 V systems and 24 V systems. These give only few amperes, but if the device you want to power is USB powered, such an USB adapter could work.

I wouldn't trust any "24 volt" equipment to work on a 24 volt lead-acid battery under fast charge unless specifically designed for use with lead-acid systems. Also "24 volt" equipment is far more rare than "12 volt" equipment (which might not work on a 12 volt lead-acid battery under fast charge which is around 15 volts).

Remember that a ~300 watt modified square wave inverter would draw only 6 watts of idle power, so unless your load is below 15 watts or so, it's not a problem to have an inverter. Some devices may not like the modified square wave; sine wave inverters are available too but they have somewhat larger idle power usage.

Comment: You could also consider using a buck converter to replace an inverter+wall-wart - converts the electricity once instead of twice

Comment: Yep, the cigarette lighter plug DC adapters, the USB adapters and also the 24V-to-12V adapters are indeed usually buck converters, or maybe some other SMPS converter.

Comment: Indeed, you can also get an adjustable one on a bare circuit board from a hobby electronics store for about $10, and then you can wire it up however you like and select the right voltage. Or you can use cigarette lighter equipment.

Comment: I actually did set up a 12V battery system using cigarette lighter equipment and one of those converters to get 5V. My experience: the converter was flawless, but cigarette lighter plugs and sockets are crap, so if you want to use cigarette lighter stuff, you may want to dismantle it and attach your own connector instead.

Comment: Essentially 24V kit that's meant to be installed in trucks (or boats etc.) should be fine, but 24V stuff meant to be put in houses may be vulnerable.  So you can get fridges that would work fine, for example (I have one like [this](https://leisurelines.net/waeco-crx80-camper-compressor-fridge-freezer-boat-12v--24v-6721-p.asp) in my van and it's 12/24V) as well as lighting.

Comment: A good source of DC can be universal laptop power supplies.  I have one that take 12V-24V or mains as input, and the output can be chosen from something like 12, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 24V with an auxiliary 5V.  There are also 24V-input PC (ATX) PSUs designed for automotive applications with a wide input range (e.g. 18-36V - watch you don't over-discharge your batteries)

Comment: @user253751 for 5V/USB, you can just get an adaptor designed for wiring in.  The one I fitted to my van is dual USB plus dual lighter sockets (I have that switched by the ignition; the built-in lighter socket is always on, risking my battery during long periods without driving).  Mine is inefficient because it uses a linear regulator, but it's also 12 years old